# Angular-Translate UrlLoader

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate, angular-i18n

I am having an issue about angular-translate useurlloader.My config is on angular side ;

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader(ALL_CONSTANTS.AdminApiEndPointPrefix + "UtilitiesAPI/getResources");

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

And my web api side is;

```
 public async Task<string> GetAllResourceTexts(string culture)
    {

        var ret =  "{'key' : 'value'}";
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret);
    }
```

But i cant see the translation on my view ;

```
<p>{{'key' | translate}}</p>
```

What should i do ? How should i return that key value pair from web api ? Need help.

PS: I solved. The problem was returning JSON format from api. When i fix that my problem is solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. The problem was returning JSON format from api. When i fix that my problem is solved..

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the `$translate` service in the templates it must be injected into your controller that handles the template:

```
app.controller('myController', function($translate){
  //controller code here
  // also can try to use
  // var myTranslated = $translate.instant('key');
});
```

Comment: nope it is not the problem. But i solved this thanks.